# Typescript "do while" gives unexpected results

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following while loop:

```
  onTryExport(dt?:DataTable){
    const totals = 21;//this.totalRecords;
    const paginatorval = 5;//this.paginatorval;
    const fetched = 0;
    const i =0;

   do{

      if ( i > (totals-i) ) {

     fetched+=(totals-i); //executed twice

    }else{

       fetched+=paginatorval;
   }

     console.log(fetched);
     i+= paginatorval;

 }while(i<totals);
}
```

THe abopve `console.log()` outputs

```
5, 10, 15,21,22
```

What I expected was

```
5,10,15,20,21
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: consts aren't mutable. You should use var

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you actually wanted?

Rather than: `if ( i > (totals - i) ) {`

Try: `if ( i > (totals - paginatorval) ) {`

```
const totals = 21;//this.totalRecords;
const paginatorval = 5;//this.paginatorval;
const fetched = 0;
const i = 0;

do {
  if ( i > (totals - paginatorval) ) {
    fetched += (totals - i); //asdf
  } else {

    fetched+=paginatorval;

  }

  console.log(fetched);

  i += paginatorval;

} while(i < totals);
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's go through iterations:

#### Cycle 0

```
totals = 21; 
paginatorval = 5;
fetched = 0;
i = 0;
fetched => 5
console.log(5);
i => 5
```

#### Cycle 1

```
totals = 21; 
paginatorval = 5;
fetched = 5;
i = 5;
fetched => 10
console.log(10);
i => 10
```

#### Cycle 2

```
totals = 21; 
paginatorval = 5;
fetched = 10;
i = 10;
fetched => 15
console.log(15);
i => 15
```

#### Cycle 3

```
totals = 21; 
paginatorval = 5;
fetched = 15;
i = 15;
fetched => 21 // !!! because (15 > (21-15)) is true
console.log(21);
i => 20
```

#### Cycle 4

```
totals = 21; 
paginatorval = 5;
fetched = 21;
i = 20;
fetched => 22 // !!! because (20 > (21-20)) is true
console.log(22);
i => 25
```

As you can see, everything breaks on "Cycle 3", because your `if` statement is going to a different branch. This has nothing to do with typescript, though